# Best practices for returning a variable Omit return value from function?

Tags: typescript, types, return

I have a function that originally had a return type of

```
Promise<Record<
ReturnType,
Omit<SomeInterface, 'key1' | 'key2'>>>
```

i.e. previously we knew that `key2` would always be omitted.

Now, the function should return the same type, but `key2` may or may not be omitted. Is there some way to do this, such as

```
Promise<Record<
ReturnType,
Omit<SomeInterface, 'key1' | 'key2'>> |
Record<
ReturnType,
Omit<SomeInterface, 'key1'>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
type OptionalProperty<O, K extends keyof O> = Pick<Partial<O>, K> & Omit<O, K>;
type T = Promise<Record<ReturnType, OptionalProperty<Omit<SomeInterface, 'key1'>, 'key2'>>>;
```

Answer (score 1):

After `Omit`ing it, you can add it back as an optional property.

Something like:

```
Promise<
  Record<
    ReturnType,
    Omit<SomeInterface, 'key1' | 'key2'> & { key2?: SomeInterface['key2'] }
  >
>
```